# Lua, best way to create static advanced item ID tables or mapping?

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures, lua

I was trying to create a sort of enumeration or table that can be indexed easily by accessing its "ItemID" directly by the index.

```lua
local id = 0
function ID(set)
    if (set) then
        id = set
    else
        id = id + 1
    end

    return id
end


local test = {
    [ID()] = {
        "item1"
    };
    
    [ID()] = {
        "item2"
    };
    
    [ID(30)] = { -- item3 is indexed through 30
        "item3"
    };
    
    [ID()] = { -- 31
        "item4"
    };

    [ID()] = { -- 32
        "item5"
    };
}

print(test, #test)
```

The problem is, if you check `#test` it will say `2` instead of `4`. This is because when `ID(30)` is used to skip the indexing to 30, it will turn it into a string, which doesn't sound ideal for networking functions.

The point of this is to create a table that will have fixed number IDs and to maintain the order in the table.

So, I am wondering for better ways to create tables like these. The reason why the indexes of the tables should never change, is due to data structure. So that the saved values will always point to what it is supposed to point to.

Aka. let's say I insert `item6` before `item2`. `item2` would no longer have the ID 2.

I could do something like this.

```lua
    {
        _id = 33,
        "item6"
    };
```

But the problem is, I won't be able to index it as `test[33]` to access `item6`. And I am trying to find out a way to compromise this issue.

The reason I wanna keep the table indexes as a number, is so that the entries are directly ordered and don't have to go through `table.sort`.

Maybe something similar like in [Best way to have string key tables in order by how they were put in the code, in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985310/best-way-to-have-string-key-tables-in-order-by-how-they-were-put-in-the-code-in) would apply. But you would end up with 2 tables, but maybe that's the point I guess.

Unless there's a way to keep everything in one table using metatables?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's examine your "autoincremented" IDs using a simplified example:

```lua
local id = 0
function ID(set)
    if set then
        id = set
    else
        id = id + 1
    end
    return id
end

local test = {
    [ID()] = 1,
    [ID()] = 2,
    [ID(30)] = 3,
    [ID()] = 4,
    [ID()] = 5,
}
```

This right there is *undefined behavior* in that you *can't know the table keys you will get* since the table constructor assignments may be executed *in any order*.

> The problem is, if you check `#test` it will say `2` instead of `4`. This is because when `ID(30)` is used to skip the indexing to 30, it will turn it into a string, which doesn't sound ideal for networking functions.

Nothing is turned into a string; this is just how the length operator works. It could've returned 32 just as well. Your table will *usually* look as follows (again, it might look completely different since the order of assignments is undefined):

```lua
local test = {[1] = 1, [2] = 2, [30] = 3, [31] = 4, [32] = 5}
```

The first "gap" is after `2`, so `2` is a valid length.

The next "gap" is after `32`, so `32` is a valid length just as well.

Both are not what you want: You're interested in how many entries the table holds.

> The point of this is to create a table that will have fixed number IDs and to maintain the order in the table.

So you're looking for a set data structure that supports the following operations:

- Add element, giving you the ID of the added element;
- Get an element by ID;
- Remove element by ID;
- In-order iteration of all elements ("to maintain the order in the table")

The naive solution here would be to keep both a list for the order and a hash map for fast lookup. However, removing an element from the list would then run in linear time.

I'd suggest a simple linked approach where each element points to its successor & predecessor paired with a hash map that maps from ID to element.

All in all, this data structure might look as follows (implementing only a *single, global instance* for the sake of simplicity):

```lua
local id = 0 -- autoincremented id
local by_id = {} -- map [id] = entry
local head, tail -- doubly linked list

-- Add a value, returning an ID
function add(value)
    id = id + 1
    local entry = {id = id, value = value, prev = tail}
    if tail then
       tail.next = entry
       entry.prev = tail
    else
       head = entry
    end
    tail = entry
    by_id[id] = entry
    return id
end

-- Get a value by ID
function get(id)
    return assert(by_id[id]).value
end

-- Remove a value by ID, returns the value
function remove(id)
    local entry = assert(by_id[id])
    if entry.prev then
        entry.prev.next = entry.next
    else -- entry is head
        head = entry.next -- update head
    end
    if entry.next then
        entry.next.prev = entry.prev
    else -- entry is tail
        tail = entry.prev -- update tail
    end
    by_id[id] = nil
    return entry.value
end

local function idnext(_, id)
    local next_entry
    if id == nil then
        _, next_entry = next(by_id)
    else
        local entry = assert(by_id[id])
        next_entry = entry.next
    end
    if next_entry == nil then return end
    return next_entry.id, next_entry.value
end

-- Iterator over `id, value` pairs, inorder
function idpairs()
    return idnext, nil, nil
end
```

Usage:

```lua
> add("foo")
1
> add("bar")
2
> add("baz")
3
> for id, val in idpairs() do print(id, val) end
1   foo
2   bar
3   baz
> remove(2)
bar
> for id, val in idpairs() do print(id, val) end
1   foo
3   baz
```

For practical purposes, you'll want to:

1. Make this something like a "class"
2. Accordingly, properly namespace all functions

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up with this.

```lua
local function mapIDs(t)
    local metaMap = {}
    
    for key, value in pairs(t) do
        metaMap[tostring(value._id)] = key
    end
    
    return metaMap
end


local test = {
    {
        _id = 1,
        data = "item1",
    };

    {
        _id = 20,
        data = "item2",
    };

    {
        _id = 4,
        data = "item3",
    };
}

local metaMap = mapIDs(test)


setmetatable(test, {__index = {_stored = metaMap}})

print(test._stored)
```

would output

```
{
    ["1"] = 1,
    ["20"] = 2,
    ["4"] = 3
}
```